# Web Based Proxy Server Can Mask My Ip Address?

Tags: proxy, webserver, isp

Web Based Proxcy Server Can Mask My Ip Address From My ISP Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much can disguise you from your own ISP aside from some sort of VPN or other tunel, but that is not possible "we based". You question is very vague, so a more helpful answer is not possible. What do you want your address masking for?

Answer (score 1):

Your ISP always knows your IP address - they give it to you.
Websites you are surfing also know your IP address, unless you use a proxy.